# Calculate loan payments & when the payment was satisfed - partial payments allowed

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been writing SQL queries for years but I'm stuck on this one.

I've got 2 tables in MySQL:

- LOANPAYMENTSDUE includes `LoanPaymentsDueId`, `LoanId`, `AmtDue`, `DueDate`
- LOANPAYMENTS includes `LoanPaymentsId`, `LoanId`, `AmtPaid`, `PaidDate`

The relationship between the tables is the `LoanId` and not the specific payment that is due. In a perfect world the `DueDate = PaidDate` and the `AmtDue = AmtPaid`.  However, what is making this complex for me is no relationship between the `LoanPaymentsDueId` and the `LoanPaymentsId`. The relationship only exists at the `LoanId` allowing for partial payments to be made on a single LOANPAYMENTSDUE payment.

I've researched the web trying to find the right query to **create a report showing the date that each LOANPAYMENTSDUE was satisfied.**  This requires calculating the balance as of the LOANPAYMENTSDUE.DueDate because there can be payments missed and a new payment should satisfy the balance of the oldest LOANPAYMENTSDUE payment.

Here is the sample data and table scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE LOANPAYMENTSDUE (
LoanPaymentsDueId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, LoanId BIGINT(20)
, AmtDue double NOT NULL
, DueDate date NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (LoanPaymentsDueId)
);

INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTSDUE (LoanId, AmtDue, DueDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-07-15');
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTSDUE (LoanId, AmtDue, DueDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-08-15');
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTSDUE (LoanId, AmtDue, DueDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-09-15');
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTSDUE (LoanId, AmtDue, DueDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-10-15');
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTSDUE (LoanId, AmtDue, DueDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-11-15');

CREATE TABLE LOANPAYMENTS (
LoanPaymentsId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, LoanId BIGINT(20)
, AmtPaid double NOT NULL
, PaidDate date NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (LoanPaymentsId)
);

INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-07-15'); /* Full pmt on due date */
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-08-10'); /* Full pmt a few days early */
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-09-22'); /* Full pmt a week late */
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2013-10-18'); /* Partial pmt a few days late */
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2013-11-07');/* Partial pmt 3 weeks late and satisfies the 10/15/2013 balance on this date */
INSERT INTO LOANPAYMENTS (LoanId, AmtPaid, PaidDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2013-11-22');/* Full pmt a week late and satisfies the 11/15/2013 pmt due */
```

The report query should simply provide the PAIDDATE when each LOANPAYMENTSDUE was satisfied. Using the table data above the report would be as follows:

```
LOANID     LOANPAYMENTSDUEID     AMTDUE     DUEDATE          PAIDDATE
1          1                     100        2013-07-15       2013-07-15    
1          2                     100        2013-08-15       2013-08-10
1          3                     100        2013-09-15       2013-09-22
1          4                     100        2013-10-15       2013-11-07
1          5                     100        2013-11-15       2013-11-22
```

Comment: wow this one is real challenging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with these two queries, that return all of the rows with a running total column:

```
SELECT
  LoanId, DueDate,
  CASE WHEN LoanId=@last_LoanId THEN @Due:=@Due+AmtDue
                                ELSE @Due:=AmtDue END total_due,
  @last_LoanId:=LoanId
FROM
  LOANPAYMENTSDUE, (SELECT @last_LoanId:=NULL, @Due:=NULL) t;

SELECT
  LoanId, PaidDate,
  CASE WHEN LoanId=@last_LoanId THEN @Paid:=@Paid+AmtPaid
                                ELSE @Paid:=AmtPaid END total_paid,
  @last_LoanId:=LoanId
FROM
  LOANPAYMENTS, (SELECT @last_LoanId:=NULL, @Paid:=NULL) t;
```

and then you could use a LEFT JOIN on due.LoanId=due.LoanId AND total_due<=total_paid, and a GROUP BY to get the minimum date where the join succeded:

```
SELECT
  ld.LoanId, ld.DueDate, MIN(lp.PaidDate)
FROM
  (SELECT
     LoanId, DueDate,
     CASE WHEN LoanId=@last_LoanId1 THEN @Due:=@Due+AmtDue ELSE @Due:=AmtDue END total_due,
     @last_LoanId1:=LoanId
   FROM
     LOANPAYMENTSDUE, (SELECT @last_LoanId1:=NULL, @Due:=NULL) t1) ld
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     LoanId, PaidDate,
     CASE WHEN LoanId=@last_LoanId2 THEN @Paid:=@Paid+AmtPaid ELSE @Paid:=AmtPaid END total_paid,
     @last_LoanId2:=LoanId
   FROM
     LOANPAYMENTS, (SELECT @last_LoanId2:=NULL, @Paid:=NULL) t2) lp
  ON
    ld.LoanId=lp.LoanId AND ld.total_due<=lp.total_paid
GROUP BY
  ld.LoanId, ld.DueDate
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c170/3).

Comment: Thanks fthiella! I like your solution and after testing different scenarios it works great. I like seeing the 2 different data sets with the running totals. The LEFT JOIN based on the total_due and total_paid works great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when the amount is paid it's paid in portion or remaining amount in whole, you check based on Total Amount Due and Total Amount Paid by matching those up. Here's the [sqlFiddle example of your data and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dc1b5/15/0)

```
SELECT T1.LoanId,
       T1.LoanPaymentsDueId,
       T1.AmtDue,
       T1.DueDate,
       T2.PaidDate
FROM
   (SELECT
     LD.LoanPaymentsDueId,
     LD.LoanId,
     LD.DueDate,
     LD.AmtDue,
     (SELECT Sum(AmtDue)
        FROM LOANPAYMENTSDUE LD1
       WHERE LD1.DueDate <= LD.DueDate
         AND LD1.LoanId = LD.LoanId
     )as AmtDueTotal
    FROM
    LOANPAYMENTSDUE LD
   )T1,
   (SELECT
     L.LoanPaymentsId,
     L.LoanId,
     L.PaidDate,
     (SELECT Sum(AmtPaid)
        FROM LOANPAYMENTS L1
       WHERE L1.PaidDate <= L.PaidDate
         AND L1.LoanId = L.LoanId
      )as AmtPaidTotal
   FROM LOANPAYMENTS L
   )T2
WHERE
    T1.LoanId = T2.LoanId
AND T1.LoanId = 1
AND T1.AmtDueTotal = T2.AmtPaidTotal;
```

Comment: well that was a little fun